# Is there any way to create an alias of a specific FnMut?

Tags: syntax, rust, traits, type-alias

I want to work with `FnMut(&[f32]) -> f32`,
to not copy/paste full signature, I want to introduce some kind of alias, but

```
type Boo = FnMut(&[f32]) -> f32;

fn f<F: Boo>(mut f: F) {}
```

Causes a compiler error:

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found type alias `Boo`
 --> src/main.rs:3:13
  |
3 |     fn f<F: Boo>(mut f: F) {}
  |             ^^^ type aliases cannot be used for traits
```

I then tried:

```
trait Boo: FnMut(&[f32]) -> f32 {}

fn f<F: Boo>(mut f: F) {}
```

it compiled, but if I try to use `Boo` in place of trait in another place:

```
trait Boo: FnMut(&[f32]) -> f32 {}

struct X(Vec<Box<Boo>>);
```

I get:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Output` (from the trait `std::ops::FnOnce`) must be specified
 --> src/main.rs:3:18
  |
3 | struct X(Vec<Box<Boo>>);
  |                  ^^^ missing associated type `Output` value
```

Is there any way to create an alias of a specific `FnMut` which I can use 
instead of `FnMut(&[f32]) -> f32`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trait aliases are not currently part of the language. However, there is an [accepted RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1733) for exactly that. It's hard to predict exactly when it will be implemented, but accepting the RFC represents a commitment to implement it at some point in the future.

The reason for your error is that your `Boo` trait is a subtype of `FnMut` and any implementation must also provide the required associated type `Output`. But the compiler still doesn't know which implementation will be provided, so you need to tell it what the type of `Output` will be:

```
struct X(Vec<Box<Boo<Output = f32>>>);
```

This is a little clunky, and I feel like it's an area for improvement. Intuitively, it seems that `Output` could be inferred from `-> f32`, but I could be wrong here.

Even with that error fixed, `Boo` is strictly a subtype of `FnMut(&[f32])` so you can't just provide any closure where `Boo` is expected. That closure must also implement your trait. You can do this as a blanket implementation for all `FnMut(&[f32]) -> f32`, like this:

```
impl <F> Boo for F where F: FnMut(&[f32]) -> f32 {}
```

Now any `Boo` is an `FnMut(&[f32]) -> f32` (by subtyping), and any `FnMut(&[f32]) -> f32` is a `Boo` (by the blanket implementation).

Comment: Yes, I read about about this RFC before ask question, question is what to do now, with current stable/beta compiler. Hacks/tricks/macroses